# How to add the jar file into the build path

Tags: android, jar

currently i am working on the nd file upload and download from ftp server to android. now i am having  the jar file which i need to use in my application.can to please suggest me how to add jar file into the build path.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11579339/356895) might be useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

Right click on `project`-> `properties`-> `Java Build Path`-> `Libraries`-> `Add External Jars`-> select the jar file where it is in your Pc-> click ok.

Answer (score 1):

In your .classpath file which should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK" />        
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

add a line

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="<path to your .jar file>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the entry

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK" />
```

is in your .classpath then you can change the android.jar in the build path simply by selecting which Android API level you want in project-> properties-> Android (the build path updates automatically)